# I am stuck in grub rescue HELP

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

So my Linux experience began a week ago. I thought that Ubuntu is a great project so switched to it instead of Windows  as I saw that just replacing it was easier and less tedious.
So I made the backup image plus the Windows Recovery on a USB stick (I tested if it worked or not before installing Ubuntu and it worked) then I decided that it was time that I switch back to Windows. The USB stick is on the first slot of boot order in the BIOS but it still boots Ubuntu instead of the Windows recovery USB.
So I tried to uninstall grub and now I'm stuck in grub rescue and the usb stick still doesn't boot even though it is supposed to boot first.

Comment: Nope I have tried the solutions in all 6 answers before and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reinstall windows or run it live off the usb? 
A couple options for either:
It is not automatically booting because of a misconfiguration in you bios. I would first repair grub, then launch into bios and manually select the usb to boot from. (Not just changing boot order but 'boot menu' itself.)

Research BIOS settings for you make and model of computer and specifically pay attention to mentions of UEFI and secure boot, as these are likely culprits

Comment: I tried choosing it manually and it just keeps on booting grub rescue and I tried the stick on another pc and it worked fine

Comment: Let it rescue before you attempt to do anything. Either recover it or do a full wipe. The best bet may be to make an ubuntu live disk to work on that machine